# Why doesn't Mono.fromRunnable return Mono<Void>?

Tags: java, project-reactor

`Runnable` returns `void` in Java. Why does `Mono.fromRunnable` return `Mono<T>` instead of `Mono<Void>`?

Comment: Before using any tag you should read it carefully. The mono tag has nothing to do with your "Mono", so don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1):

[API documentation of Mono#fromRunnable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) states about the type parameter:

> The generic type of the upstream, which is preserved by this operator

It allows to use it as part of an operation chain without altering the resulting type.

*Example*:

This code:

```java
Mono<String> myMono = Mono.empty();
myMono = myMono.switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromRunnable(() 
         -> System.err.println("WARNING, empty signal !")));

String value = myMono.block(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
System.out.println("Exported value is "+value);
```

*Produces*:

```
WARNING, empty signal !
Exported value is null
```

The code above compiles fine, and provide a Mono for a String without having to add additional casts.

The posted example is not very good, but I suppose that this signature allows to use `fromRunnable` to launch side-effects in some case, without disturbing value type of the overall operation chain.

It's kinda like `Mono.empty()` with additional computing embedded with it.